# How to move *simultaneously* two points which are given as inputs for an indicator?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have two pairs of variables, which are taken as inputs via input.time and input.value. By pairing each of the input.time with one input.value by setting to them a same inline argument, these give two points in the graph, which can very nicely be moved with the mouse around independently.

Here is a minimal code sample (I'm working with log charts only, hence why I use a logarithmic line instead of a regular one):

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

var int initialTime = 0
if bar_index == 0 
    initialTime := time

var x1Time = input.time(timestamp("27 Mar 2022 12:00"), "Time1", "Point 1 X", group = "Point 1 - Ascendent", inline= "Pt1", confirm = true)
var x1 = math.floor((x1Time-initialTime) / (1000*timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period)))
var y1 = input.price(24.295, "Value1", tooltip= "Point 1 Y", group = "Point 1 - Ascendent", inline= "Pt1", confirm = true)
var x2Time = input.time(timestamp("19 Apr 2024 12:00"), "Time2", "Point 2 X", group = "Point 1 - Ascendent", inline= "Pt2", confirm = true)
var x2 = math.floor((x2Time-initialTime) / (1000*timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period)))
var y2 = input.price(50.509, "Value2", tooltip= "Point 2 Y", group = "Point 1 - Ascendent", inline= "Pt2", confirm = true)

slope = (math.log10(y2)-math.log10(y1))/(x2-x1)
coeff = y1/math.pow(10,slope*x1)

log_trend_prices(m,k) => k * math.pow(10, m * bar_index)
```

Is there a way (via code or drawing tools) to move them AT THE SAME TIME (i.e. so that their relative position stays fixed)?

I've tried the following, but nothing seems to work unfortunately:

- There seems to be no drawing tools to select both points at the same time; only moving them one at a time works.
- Code-wise, I tried implementing a setting in the indicator, via an input.bool, that when checked should have the effect of "blocking the second point" relative to the first, i.e. if this bool is true then moving around the first point should move around the second as well, keeping its relative position with respect to the first point fixed (i.e. the line should not change slope).
  I didn't manage to implement this correctly (if it is even possible).

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: no, there is no such way to do it not from the chart, nor from the pine script, because `input().*` function accept only constant values, so you can't add threshold to one input from another